# SEND SMS not working inside MyJavaScriptInterface - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am sending message by calling function through `WebView`.

`Toast.makeText` function is working fine ( show alert message) but in same function if i placed send sms code then it doesn't work.

here is my code

```
    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void sendsmss(String phoneNumber, String message) {

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);


     }





}
```

`WebView` code to call function

```
onClick="AndroidFunction.sendsmss('1234567890','hello world ');"
```

All required classes imported.

I successfully sent sms by placing smsmanager code inside onCreate function

Comment: actually problem is that sms send if i placed code inside onCreate function so there is no issue with SmsManager.
but if i want to call function inside class MyJavaScriptInterface then it does not work. is there any issue to function calling method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@JavascriptInterface` annotation to sendsms method. Without this annotation your  method couldn't be called from javascript

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

Context mContext;

MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void sendsmss(String phoneNumber, String message) {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

 }
}
```

Comment: One more question for reverse, i added following code to call javascript function just after sms method but it doesn't call.
is there any need to add any annotation?     

String msgToSend="hello i am from android app";            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+msgToSend+"\")");

javascript function "callFromActivity" is defined at webpage .

Comment: May be your msgToSend contains the '\n', '\r' and so on characters? Anyway, debugging of "java to javascript" interaction is difficult.  If your android API level >= 19, turn on webview debugging with `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {           WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);}` and go to chrome://inspect in Google Chrome browser at desktop. For more information https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

**Try the SMS via intent,**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);
```

Edited,

Add permissions in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question that sms sent when i placed smsmanager code inside onCreate function but i want to trigger sms through webpage so i added code inside myjavainterface  class.
so there is no problem in smsmanage or permissions, i think calling method incorrect.
please review question once.

Comment: i am trying in mobile phone by installing my app.